# How to delete an old commit completely on bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

very weird story but the other day i was working on a code with my team and while playing around i typed some really embarrassing stuff inside the IDE. I forgot to delete those stuff and by accident i committed and pushed. I deleted the commit from bitbucket by using the git rebase -i HEAD~3 and marked the commit as "drop" but everytime anyone pushes something, it shows up again in the commit tab in bitbucket, and it also shows up on the graphs. Is there a way to delete the commit permenantly that no one can restore it or even see it was there in the beginning? I don't want to be humiliated in front of my boss.

Comment: Errare humanum est. Delete those stuff and make a new commit to fix it. If being asked, just admit it. That's all. Now the unwanted commit could be reachable from one or more branches or tags. If you want to remove it from all of these refs, you will probably make a much bigger mistake by changing the commit history that has been published to your colleagues. It will be a disaster. Take it easy. Afterall almost all the bugs are created by programmers, aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

> git rebase -i HEAD~3 and marked the commit as "drop"

Those are local operation: you would still need to '`git push --force`' in order for the remote BitBucket repo to replace its history with your revised one.

And you would need to ask your colleagues to reset their own local branch to the new history

```
 cd /path/to/colleague/repo
 git checkout master # assuming they are working on master
 git stash
 git fetch
 git reset --hard origin/master
 git stash pop
```

(They better make a copy of their work in progress to be on the safe side)